# SQL query to search for records containing an apostrophe (')

Tags: sql, sql-like, apostrophe

I'm ingesting data into IBM MDM and we are finding source records with row key's containing an apostrophe (') which MDM cannot accept and therefore rejects the records.  I want to query the source records to count how many records are affected, but with SQL apostrophes open and close text strings.  Is there a way to make a query like

select count (*)
from table1
where field1 like '%'%' ;

Basically, I want to be able to search for a string of letters that have an apostrophe in it like...roundy's

Comment: Usually 2 x `'` escape a `'` so `like '%''%'`

Answer (score 1):

Use backslash to escape special characters. To get `aa'bb` use `aa\'bb`.

[Escape characters](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSWSR9_11.0.0/com.ibm.pim.ctm.doc/content/pim_ref_escapecharacters.html)

Answer (score 1):

" instead of ' will get you what you want

Comment: Could you please make an example or add some more explanation why this would help?